# I've been arrested once in Spain, does it affect my future application for visa to Spain or any other Schengen countries?

Tags: visas, air-travel, schengen, europe, spain

I have been arrested once in Spain for one day because of a fight when I had a student visa, does it affect my future application for visa to Spain or any other Schengen Countries when i want to go there as a tourist or for work?

By the way, the problem was a fight with my girlfriend, they put me in jail for one night and then released me with some terms which include not talking to my girlfriend for 4 months and doing some works when i come back to Spain. Will I be banned from entry in the future?

Comment: Please add more information. Were you charged and convicted? What level of crime (AKA misdeanor / felony), released with a "caution" or warning. It will depend if you have a police record and if so, what kind.

Comment: Yes and they released me with some terms, it says if i go back to Spain I have to do some works, the thing is that it was a fight with my girlfriend and they told us not to see each other for 4 months :\

Comment: I don't know about the other things sorry, but it was a jail for a night and then they let me go with terms without a court because i was leaving soon. Will i be banned from entry?

Comment: John, would you please edit the question and include this information there? That way people don't have to read the comments too. Thank you!

Comment: I doubt this would cause a problem.

Comment: Is there any answer?

Comment: Please clarify what crime you were charged with exactly.